# Why is Wordpress still using http for some urls after moving to https?

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I discovered a strange behaviour for Wordpress. I just moved from a *http* to a *https* site, I updated the variables *siteurl* and *home* according to the docs, but got mixed contents served by my Apache server.

So I started the WP shell (Wordpress Command Line Interface), and I discovered something that looks like an inconsistency:

```
$ wp shell 
wp> echo bloginfo('siteurl');
https://www.romanliturgy.org
wp> echo bloginfo('home');
https://www.romanliturgy.org
wp> echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
http://www.romanliturgy.org/wordpress/wp-content/themes/romanliturgy
```

It is not normal in my eyes that when your site is at https://www.romanliturgy.org, your stylesheet and pictures are fetched at http://www.romanliturgy.org.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Strange: I expected the output of `echo bloginfo('home');` should be http://www.romanliturgy.org/wordpress instead of http://www.romanliturgy.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is solved.

My website stays behind a reverse proxy server. My problem was probably due to a missing setting in this proxy server. The administrator added this line in the settings:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https'
```

As far as I can see, everything is working as expected with the most browsers. Only Chromium browser still redirects *https* requests to the old *http* site, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) tool to do a search and replace of the old domain like so:

`wp search-replace http://www.romanliturgy.org https://www.romanliturgy.org`

You can also add `--dry-run` to the end of that to just check if there are any instances of the http version of the domain.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I ran the command, but the problem is still there. At least, I am sure there is no instance of the old http URL in my database.